# Error throwing while sending an email using laravel

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

Error throwing while sending an email using laravel after migration the web application to a new server. It was working fine on the previous server.

[image]

Relevant error description edited in from comments:

> [2018-01-25 13:31:10] production.ERROR: ErrorException: mkdir(): No
>   such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/jbservice/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/c‌​lasses/Swift/KeyCach‌​e/Disk$
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleErro‌​r(2,
>   'mkdir(): No suc...', '/var/www/html/j...', 273, Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/jbservice/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/c‌​lasses/Swift/KeyCach‌​e/DiskKeyCache.php(2‌​73):
>   mkdir('/tmp/68d392a3e3...')

Relevant code edited from comments:

```
Mail::send('dashboard.emails.createticket', $data , function ($message) 
use ($data) { $message->subject('New Ticket: ' . $data['subject']) 
    ->to("atif@gmail.com") 
    ->from('HERE COMES THE SENDER EMAIL'); });
```

Comment: Need more information! Why create a directory? and how is it created?

Comment: I am just sending an email through laravel, not creating directory. The email use a email template that exists in my views folder.

Comment: @AtifJaved that is the error you get and not the code. We can't help you if we don't see your code

Comment: @SapneshNaik just shared the code in the previous comment, please check

Comment: By the way its running fine on the local system but not on the production server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your log.

If it  show the SwiftMailer was trying to create cache in default /tmp folder :

To solve the issue,  change the TMPDIR environment variable in the boot() method of app/Providers/AppServiveProvider.php.

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    /**
     * Somehow PHP is not able to write in default /tmp directory and SwiftMailer was failing.
     * To overcome this situation, we set the TMPDIR environment variable to a new value.
     */
    if (class_exists('Swift_Preferences')) {
        \Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setTempDir(storage_path().'/tmp');
    } else {
        \Log::warning('Class Swift_Preferences does not exists');
    }
}
```

Please make sure that the new “tmp” folder location is writable by the web server.

Comment: did u try that change in appserviceprovider.php

Comment: Hey, I just added that code, but still the same issue.

Comment: check the permission to the temp folder in storage in server

Comment: Resolved the issue, by making a tmp directory in the storage folder. Thanks! for your help

Comment: yes u should make that one because its in boot function that temporary file are stored in tmp folder

Comment: Adding /tmp to open_basedir worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as expected at multiple places.