# LARAVEL "mkdir(): No such file or directory" SEND MAIL

Tags: php, laravel, email, mkdir

I'm trying to send email from laravel, but I keep geting this error:

> mkdir(): No such file or directory

The code is:

```
Mail::send('resetpassword', ['data' => $user], function ($message) use ($user) {
  $message->to($user->email, $user->nome);
  $message->subject("alteração de senha");
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440342/error-throwing-while-sending-an-email-using-laravel

Comment: Well, no, but I could solve changing some folders permissions and doing that. Thank you. Just for record my log files where empty, only my console was showing the error.

Comment: Error mentions `mkdir` but your code doesn't include the use of this function

Comment: well, that`s the trick isn`t kkkk, I think the Mail class at some point try to create a tmp folder to store the mail temp data (attachments and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this crystal clear, for some reason laravel tmp folder did not exist in my storage folder, the first step was to create a tmp folder with the right permissions.
After that I had to edit my app/Providers/AppServiveProvider.php as pointed in this question: [Error throwing while sending an email using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440342/error-throwing-while-sending-an-email-using-laravel), and the final step was go to my config/mail.php and set all the variables necessary to send email ( I don't understand why, since my env files already had all necessary data).

Comment: Oi, Guilherme! The problem is because the open_basedir restriction in PHP. For me it just worked adding /tmp to the openbase_dir. More info here https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000278993-A-website-hosted-in-Plesk-is-not-accessible-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-File-is-not-within-the-allowed-path-s-